# Rounding summarize function results in error

Tags: r, rounding, apply

Trying to output summary statistics using `summarize` from `rockchalk` package.
Want the stats to be rounded to 2 decimals. I get an error message when 
using `round` on `summarize`.

```
library(rockchalk)
M1 <- structure(c(0.18, 0.2, 0.24, 0.35, -0.22, -0.17, 0.28, -0.28, -0.14, 0.03, 0.87, -0.2, 0.06, -0.1, -0.72, 0.18, 0.01, 0.31, -0.36, 0.61, -0.16, -0.07, -0.13, 0.01, -0.09, 0.26, -0.14, 0.08, -0.62, -0.2, 0.3, -0.21, -0.11, 0.05, 0.06, -0.28, -0.27, 0.17, 0.42, -0.05, -0.15, 0.05, -0.07, -0.22, -0.34, 0.16, 0.34, 0.1, -0.12, 0.24, 0.45, 0.37, 0.61, 0.9, -0.25, 0.02), .Dim = c(56L, 1L))

#This works
round(apply(M1, 2, mean),2)

#This works
summaryround <- function(x) {round(summary(x),2)} 
apply(M1, 2, summaryround)

#This gives error "non-numeric argument"
round(apply(M1, 2, summarize),2)

#Thought this would work but also gives error "non-numeric argument"
summarizeround <- function(x) {round(summarize(x),2)} 
apply(M1, 2, summarizeround)
```

Any ideas? I can round the output of `summary` but want to use `summarize` 
if possible as I like to get the outputs of kurtosis and skewness in the same printout (of course, could create my own function combining `summary` and `kurtosis` and whatever I want, rather not if avoidable).

---

EDIT: should have mentioned actually running this on a large data frame; turned it into a 1 column matrix as I thought would make the reproducible example simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to extract the `numerics` field from `summarize` result. Besides, I would prefer to use `lapply` to keep the rownames of the results and use `do.call(bind,...)` if you have multiple columns to summarize.

```
summarizeround <- function(x) {round(summarize(x)$numerics,2)} 
summaryDf <- do.call(cbind, lapply(as.data.frame(M1), summarizeround))

             x
0%       -0.72
25%      -0.16
50%       0.02
75%       0.24
100%      0.90
mean      0.04
sd        0.32
var       0.10
skewness  0.45
kurtosis  0.56
NA's      0.00
N        56.00
```

Comment: Psidom would you know how to keep the column names rather than getting an "x"? Your code works great but I'm running this on a data frame with a few hundred columns, need those column names. Thanks!

Comment: You can split the summary into two steps by `summaryList <- lapply(as.data.frame(M1), summarizeround); summaryDf <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, summaryList))` and then assign the names to the reuslt dataframe `names(summaryDf) <- names(summaryList)`

Answer (score 0):

?rockchalk::summarize says the argument is to be a data frame. So, make M1 a data frame

```
M1<-as.data.frame(M1)
summarize(M1)

$numerics
              V1
0%       -0.7200
25%      -0.1625
50%       0.0150
75%       0.2400
100%      0.9000
mean      0.0400
sd        0.3152
var       0.0993
skewness  0.4485
kurtosis  0.5626
NA's      0.0000
N        56.0000

$factors
NULL
```

And to get the rounding

```
> round(summarize(M1)[[1]],2)
            V1
0%       -0.72
25%      -0.16
50%       0.02
75%       0.24
100%      0.90
mean      0.04
sd        0.32
var       0.10
skewness  0.45
kurtosis  0.56
NA's      0.00
N        56.00
```

Comment: what is rockchalk failure msg?

Comment: Running `round(summarize(M1),2)` gave same error. The code is intended for a large number of columns, so selecting column 1 would not do. Thanks very much anyways!